# Mapping of an unseen Field/word to an existing description (in the input data), given Field and their respective descriptions as input/training data

Tags: nlp, bert, semantic-similarity

I am working on a NLP problem.

**Problem Statement**

Given the input of fields & Labels and the respective descriptions, the goal is to the map a new unseen field to one of the most appropriate definitions.

**Sample Dataset**

| **Label** | **Descriptions** |
| --- | --- |
| Release Date | Date of formal issuance |
| Language | The language of the dataset |

So, for any new field, I want to map the field to one of the existing definition

**Approach**

I used a bert model for embedding combined with cosine similarity to compute the similarity between every new field (test unseen word) with the existing fields and take the definition of the most similar existing field.

**Challenges**

As my dataset is very small, the results are not great.

**Question to the Community**

Is it possible to generate a synthetic dataset that simulates the existing dataset, in order to have a bigger dataset which is "contextually similar" to my existing dataset. That might help my results to improve.

Would greatly appreciate any assistence.

Best regards,

nitin

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. In general it doesn't work well to generate synthetic text data, text is too diverse. I'm not surprised that the performance is not great, because there's very little information that the model can use.

Comment: @Erwan Thanks for your response. So, is there some other approach which I could lookup according to you that might be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's a lot of options, at least i can't think of anything better that what you're doing. Unless there's a way to add more information to exploit, it's a very difficult task.