# How can I implement classification for this problem?

Tags: nlp, clustering, predictive-modeling, prediction

I have been thinking about the problem of "predicting" damages awarded in legal cases. For specificity, let us be given a dataset of summaries of cases of a certain flavour (say discrimination cases) that have been binned in a fixed number of "bands" by ranges of damages awarded. Then is it possible to train a custom model to be able to read the facts of a case as reported by an aggrieved party and predict which bin it would fall into should the plaintiff win. My first thought is unsupervised text clustering via NLP. Is there something more efficient that can be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, the input dataset consists of a 2 columns.
Column A - Previous Case Summary, Column B - the range/bin of damage awarded
And you want to map a new unseen case summary, to one of the existing column B values ranges/bin based on the similarity of new case summary to most similar Column A case summary text.

I recently worked on a similar problem, where instead of case summary, I had fields/labels mapped to their description and I wanted to map a new/unseen field to one of the given descriptions.
[Mapping of an unseen Field/word to an existing description (in the input data), given Field and their respective descriptions as input/training data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/112095/mapping-of-an-unseen-field-word-to-an-existing-description-in-the-input-data)

My approach was doing Bert Embedding and then doing cosine similarity on field/labels and based on the similarity value to one of the existing fields, taking its description.

This could be one of the approaches.
Let me know, if you need the sample code. Happy to help.

Comment: I think I have a decent amount of data from statutes for this to give reasonable results. It would be really helpful to play around with your code, thank you for offering!

Comment: sure, I can send you the ipynb file. How can I do this here. Maybe over the chat.

Comment: I am not sure, I don't use stackexchange that much. Is it possible for you to email it to me at chris159753@gmail.com? Its just a pet project, so I am not looking to monetise this. Happy to credit you wherever I use it.

Comment: done. Just sent.